# How to validate inputs with filter in register_setting callback

Tags: plugin-development, filters, validation

I now have this function that works well :

```
function wpPartValidate_settings( $input ) {
   if ( check_admin_referer( 'wpPart_nonce_field', 'wpPart_nonce_verify_adm' ) ) {

    // Create our array for storing the validated options
    $output = array();

    foreach( $input as $key => $value ) {

      // Check to see if the current option has a value. If so, process it.
      if( isset( $input[$key] ) ) {

        // Strip all HTML and PHP tags and properly handle quoted strings
        $output[$key] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $input[ $key ] ) );

      } // end if
    } // end foreach
  } // end if
  // Return the array processing any additional functions filtered by this action
  return apply_filters( 'wpPartValidate_settings', $output, $input );
}
```

I wonder how to implement filters into that function.

The goal is to inform the administrator that one input has not been correctly filled (with a correct email, url, numbers, date...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to rename your function to `wpPartSanitize_settings`, because this function doesn't validate anything. As it doesn't validate anything, then you aren't able to "inform" administrator that one input is invalid.

Nevertheless, to create your hook for `wpPartValidate_settings` filter, just do it like this:

```
add_filter( 'wpPartValidate_settings', 'wpse8170_sanitize_settings', 10, 2 );
function wpse8170_sanitize_settings( $output, $input ) {
    // ...
    return $output;
}
```